# App Engine Flex Deployment Fails With Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, deployment, google-app-engine

My App Engine Flex deployment fails with this error code.

`Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.   ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2022-03-02T14:50:16.393Z7.sl.2: The region asia-southeast1 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Please try again later.`

When I first witnessed it -
My app threw a 502 error. Out of the blue. No code change, no push nothing.

I tried uploading a new version, I get ^^ that error. Only this time the region was there Mumbai region. southeast2 I think.

I tried to upload multiple times to no avail. I changed the configs to start up a standard environment instance. Uploaded and it worked.

I changed the config back to Flex, it ALSO worked.

A few more successful deploys later, the same error. Only this time the standard deploy and back to flex deploy gamble did not work either.

I had to start a new project, in a different zone, the current one, Singapore, and it got deployed.
Couple of weeks later, during my next deployment, this error pops up again.

I have looked everywhere and cannot find what is going wrong.

I need to understand is it something in my code/config yaml or is it to do with GCP and it being out of resources for the flex environment.

(Standard environment deploys always work, I can't use them because I need session_affinity to use websockets. session_affinity is only available in Flex)